# Windows popup: X.exe has stopped working (Code::Blocks)

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

thanks in advance for taking a look at this.

I'm getting a Windows error message when I try to run this program I wrote in C in Code::Blocks. The funny thing is it compiles fine, and if I lower the upper bound of what I'm testing the program runs fine as well.

Details:

When I try to run the program, first I get a Windows popup that says "X.exe has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem". Shortly this changes to "X.exe has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available. (Close program)" I click the close program button, and then I see the command prompt that says "Process returned 255 <0xFF>  execution time 3.940 s  Press any key to continue".

I have Windows 8.

I'm using the GNU GCC compiler.

If I change "upto" to 100000, the program works fine.

Here's the code:

```
/************************************************
* Finds the starting integer under 1000000 that
* produces the longest Collatz sequence, and the
* length of said sequence.
*************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define upto 1000000

int main()
{
    long i;
    long long j;
    long long max = LONG_LONG_MAX;
    long length = 0;
    long number = 0;
    long penull = 0;
    long len[upto];
    for (i = 0; i < upto; i++) (len[i] = 0);
    // counts length of Collatz sequence for starting integers from 1 to 999999
    for (i = 1; i < upto; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while (j != 1)
        {
            assert (j <= (max - 1)/3);
            if (j%2 == 0) (j = j/2);
            else (j = 3*j + 1);
            len[i]++;
            if (j < i)
            {
                len[i] = len[i] + len[j];
                j = 1;
            }
        }
        // stores length of the longest sequence and the starting integer producing it
        if (len[i] > length)
            {
                length = len[i];
                number = i;
            }
        // stores a duplicate length for later comparison
        else if (len[i] == length) (penull = len[i]);
    }
    if (length == penull) (printf("There are at least two!"));
    else printf("%ld produces a Collatz sequence of length %ld", number, length + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the array `len` outside the `main` function. The size of the stack is sometimes limited, and local variables are stored on the stack. By moving it outside, you make it a global variable.